# Let $K$ be a field where $−1$ is not a square, and let $G = GL_2(K)$. If $g ∈ G$, show that $g$ has order $4$ iff $det(g) = 1$ and $trace(g) = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field where $−1$ is not a square, and let $G = GL_2(K)$. If $g ∈ G$, show that $g$ has order $4$ iff $det(g) = 1$ and $trace(g) = 0$.

Suppose $g$ is of order 4, then the minimal polynomial of $g$ should divide $x^4-1$. Now $x^4-1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$, but $-1$ is not a square in this field, so $(x^2+1)$ has no root, and the minimal polynomial divides $(x-1)(x+1)$. So, for $g \neq id$, the minimal polynomial is $(x-1)(x+1)$. The eigenvalues are two roots $1$ and $-1$, and hence the trace is $0$. However, if the trace is 0, by the formula of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2-tr(g)\lambda + det(g)=0$, the determinant should be $-1$ instead of $1$. I don't know what I got wrong.\

Also, there is a second question I have no idea of: Suppose there exist elements $a, b ∈ K$ with $a^2 + b^2 = −1$. Show that $G$ contains two elements $g, h$ of order $4$ such that $gh$ also has order $4$. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: The minimal polynomial can include $x^2 + 1$. Basically by what you say above, it should include it.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, let $g=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{pmatrix}$ and $h=\begin{pmatrix}-b&a\\a&b\end{pmatrix}$.
By the given condition $\det g=\det h =1$ and since their trace are 0, so their order are 4. Since determinant is multiplicative, clearly $\det(gh)=1$. Now you just need to verify that the trace of $gh$ is zero to conclude that $gh$ is of order 4 as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I set $h = \begin{pmatrix}b&a\\a&-b\end{pmatrix}$ at the first time, and the computation did not work out. So now, by direct computation, $gh = \begin{pmatrix}0&a^2 + b^2\\-(a^2 + b^2)&0\end{pmatrix}$. Hence the trace of $gh$ is $0$. By the statement of the first part, we can conclude $gh$ is of order 4.